# Ethernet devices wont connect to Internet

Tags: networking, ethernet

After replacing a comcast modem I have found out all of my devices running ubuntu no longer connect to the internet.
All other devices connect fine to the same network.
The devices that lost connection are all wired. Other wired devices work fine and cables work when plugged into working devices.
I have tried a few restarts and deleting the network adapter to let it reinstall on startup.
Cant really seem to find any errors. Not really sure what is the cause.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately bot that's all the info I have.